# Handle random internal 500

Tags: c#

I wrote a wrapper, which sometimes I receive an internal error 500 on the following line:

```
using(var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
     // Additional logic.
}
```

I'd like to handle the exception, but I cannot use `request.HaveResponse()` because the request technically is valid, so when my code attempts to get the response the error is thrown, for a `System.Net.WebException`.  I'd like to not wrap in an additional try catch block.  *Some logic exists to validate the status code, but did not add since that block won't rectify or impede the offending line of code in question.*

The entire method:

```
public TModel DownloadFromApi<TModel>(string url)
{
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));

     try
     {
          if(WebRequest.Create(url) is HttpWebRequest request)
          {
              request.Method = "GET";
              request.ContentType = "application/json";

              if(request.HaveResponse())
                   using(var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                   using(var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        if(stream != null)
                             using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                                  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TModel>(reader.ReadToEnd());
          }

          ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal($"Requestor did not provide response. {url}");
     }

     catch(HttpRequestException exception)
     {
          ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal("Unhandled Http Exception.");
          ApplicationProvider.Log.Fatal(exception.Format());
          throw new HttpRequestException(exception);
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you hate braces? :)

Comment: As far as I know 500 error responses are handled with try ... catch blocks. At the end a 500 means that you had a remote exception so makes sense to me.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia Personally for one layer nesting, the scope is easy to follow.  So I prefer not to add them, but my preference isn't the same as everyones.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia So no way to catch to let the code flow normally?

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. You already have try-catch block. Why do you want to wrap 500 error in another one?

Comment: @Evk I don't want to wrap it in another one, I believe an unhandled web exception is thrown on `GetResponse` that causes the application to stop executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to look like you are not using Exceptions you can always write your own extension method like (kick & dirty, I've not used an IDE):

```
public static bool HasErrorResponse(HttpWebRequest request, out WebResponse response)
{
    try
    {
        response = request.GetResponse();
        return true;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that generally frowned upon, but may be my only option to handle since request.GetResponse() errors before I can actually look at the status code.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking `HaveResponse` before you even issue a `GetResponse`?

I would replace:

```
if(request.HaveResponse())
  using(var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
```

With:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse){
    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){

    }
}
```

Comment: Was doing that to test, but I can't even get to that area to check status code because of the exception.  Also the WebRequest should hold response information.